# Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dom, position

I have this example that displays some arbitrary text from the user:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
     <%= @article.text %>    
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to know how to get the X and Y position of HTML elements such as @article.text using Ruby.

Comment: using javascript would be doable

Comment: x and y relative to what? The screen? The page? Another element? In general? Or with specific screen resolutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set some id to element

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="my-id">
    <%= @article.text %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And get position in JS with `getBoundingClientRect`

```
const getCoordinates = (element) => {
  const box = element.getBoundingClientRect()

  return {
    top: box.top + window.pageYOffset,
    right: box.right + window.pageXOffset,
    bottom: box.bottom + window.pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + window.pageXOffset
  }
}

const element = document.getElementById('my-id')

const coordinates = getCoordinates(element)

console.log(coordinates)
```

Reference:

https://javascript.info/coordinates